# Appropriate phrase for the expression "get something made"

Tags: phrase-usage

I see "get something made" used a lot in Indian English, for example in sentences like the following.

> Do you have any idea how do **I get my passport made**?

> What is the procedure of **getting the rental agreement made**?

Are these two expression idiomatic? If not, could anyone please suggest the correct usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While “get something made” is an acceptable form in some sentence constructions, it is not idiomatic (in ordinary English)  in the instances shown in the question.  In the US, those questions would be phrased as in some of the following examples.

> How do I get a passport?
>   Do you know how to get a passport?
>   What do I have to do to complete the rental agreement?
>   How do I complete the rental agreement?
>   What forms do I have to fill out?

Comment: It's certainly not idiomatic to *get a passport **made*** in "standard" English, but [here it is](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22where+I+can+get+my+passport+made%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in a book (published in New Delhi) purporting to teach "English Conversation Practice". Personally, I can't help thinking that adding the word "made" gives a strong implication that *"Where I can get my passport **made**"* means *"Where can I obtain an **illegal** passport"*.